# Is it possible to turn off bluetooth discoverability programmatically on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Of course, given that the user would permit such change.
Suppose I set the  `EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION` to be 300 second. Is there any way to halt it at the 100th second?

Answer (score 2):

Usually what you have to do is send another Discoverable intent with time 1

```
Intent discoverable = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverable.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 1);
startActivity(discoverable);
```

This is more like a hack, but it does the trick, take on count that these actions must be explicitly performed by the user.

Also for a good understanding about how to use the Bluetooth sockets protocol in Android this [tutorial](http://www.doepiccoding.com/blog/?p=232) explains in detail alot of those things...

Hope it Helps.

Regards!

Comment: You may also need    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
in your manifest file

Comment: It explicitly says "discoverable for 1 sec" on user prompt, which might confuses ordinary users, anyway to hide it?